# Get the value of same controller redirect to route with a Message in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to Laravel, i am trying to get the value of a parameter which is sent by a function name `movetotrash()` here is how my function looks like:

```
public function movetotrash($id){

        $page = Pages::where('id', $id) -> first();
        $page -> active = 0;
        $page -> save();
        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('trash','Pages Moved To Trash');

    }
```

In the same controller i have this function:

```
public function index()
    {


        $pages=Pages::where('active', 1)->get();

        //get the value of "trash" sent by function movetotrash()
        return view('pages.pages')->with('pages',$pages);
    }
```

How can i do this? I am sending this message then to the front view from the frontend so it can notify the user that the value had been successfully moved to trash.

Is there any easy way or other way of doing this? If yes then also suggest that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Dont rly get your question, you want to display message when you do function movetotrash() ?

Comment: Yes when that function execution is finished then i want to send the TRASH value to frontend so i can show a message to user.

Answer (score 0):

in your view add this code,

```
   <?php $mess = Session::get('trash'); ?>
    @if (isset($mess ))
       <div class="alert alert-error">
          {{ Session::get('trash') }}<br><br>

       </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Undefined variable: trash this is the error i am getting. When i am using this in frontend.

Comment: check the spelling of 'trash', and did you put the whole code above as it is?

Comment: Yes there was mistake at my end, which is resolved. I guess i dont need to send to route(), it can directly go using redirect method.